# Person's parameter (ability) calibration using R's package ltm

Tags: r, missing-data, item-response-theory, calibration

I have a user response ($0/1$) matrix `user_item_matrix`, which has $1000$ rows (users) and $30$ columns (items/questions). There is a lot of missing data (more than $50\%$, on average, for each user/row).

Now, I'm using `ltm` package as follows:

```
# Load package
library(ltm)

#...

# Fit the model
pl3 <- tpm(user_item_matrix, type="latent.trait", IRT.param=TRUE)

# Person parameter estimations (according to the real responses)
theta_pred = factor.scores(pl3, 
                           method='EAP',
                           resp.patterns=user_item_matrix
                           )$score.dat$Exp

# Summary of the vector of estimated parameters
summary(theta_pred)
```

It returns:

```
# Min.   1st Qu.  Median  Mean    3rd Qu.  Max. 
# 0.001  1.286    9.123   71.363  98.157   708.748
```

So, we get only positive `theta`'s and a lot of them are quite big ($>10$) which feels not right. Any ability level bigger than $6$ seems weird. Am I wrong? Is there a way to "calibrate' the estimated parameters (say, forcing them to be within $[-5,5]$)?

Can these huge ability levels be a result of the fact that I have so many missing values in my data?

Comment: Exp is not the ability estimate, it's the expected number of responses for a given pattern and model.

Comment: Thanks, @philchalmers. So, what I actually need is `z1`?

Comment: Hm, it seems to work fine. It was a silly question from my side :) 
Thanks again, @philchalmers. Are there any good resources where I can read about `ltm` and how it works (except for the package's manual)?

Comment: Or should I use `mirt` instead ;) ?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to ask about that package, mostly because I recommend using the mirt package for biased reasons...

Comment: I understand, @philchalmers :) Thanks for your help anyway. I will try `mirt` too :)